# Random walk with different probability at the origin

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process, random-walk

I'm trying to solve the following problem. Consider the random walk on the integers. At zero the probability to go right is $1/2$ and the probability to go left is $1/2$. Everywhere else going to the right has probability $p$ and going to the left has probability $1-p$. I want to find the probability of ever returning back to zero if the random walk starts at zero.

**My solution:**

We know random walk is markov chain, so call it markov chain $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$. Let's define the probability of ever returning to $i$ if the random walk starts in $i$ as $f_{ii}$ and $f_{ii}^n$ as returning to $i$ with exactly $n$ steps while $X_k\neq i$ if $0<k<n$. In this random walk there is only returning back with even number of steps, so $f_{ii}^{2n+1}=0$. Clearly:

\begin{align} 
f_{00} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} f_{00}^{2k}
\end{align}

The first term:
\begin{align}
f_{00}^{2}=p_{0,1} \cdot p_{1,0} + p_{0,-1}\cdot p_{-1,0} = \frac{1}{2} (1-p) + \frac{1}{2} p = \frac{1}{2}  
\end{align}

For the next terms we have something like (I dont write it down in formal way, because I want to know if the idea is right):
\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty} f_{00}^{2k} = p_{0,1} \cdot \mathbb{P}(\text{Ever returning to 1 without going less than 1} | X_1 = 1)\cdot p_{1,0}+ p_{0,-1} \cdot   \mathbb{P}(\text{Ever returning to -1 without going greater than -1} | X_1 = -1) \cdot p_{-1,0}
\end{align}
And that is equal to: 
\begin{align}
\frac{1-p}{2} \mathbb{P}(\text{Ever returning to 1 without going less than 1} | X_1 = 1)  + \frac{p}{2}   \mathbb{P}(\text{Ever returning to -1 without going greater than -1} | X_1 = -1)
\end{align}
If the random walk is at $1$ and has positive number of steps left before returning to $0$, then the random walk can do whatever it "wants" as long as it stays to the right side of 1. And when it eventually returns to 1 then it must take one step to the left to reach 0. The same holds for $-1$. I know  $\mathbb{P}(\text{Ever returning to 1 without going less than 1} | X_1 = 1)$ is like the probability of ever returning to 1 in one-sided random walk and that is equal to: $\frac{1}{2}(1-|2p-1|)$. The same holds for $\mathbb{P}(\text{Ever returning to -1 without going greater than -1} | X_1 = -1)$ because of symmetry.

So I end up with:
\begin{align}
f_{00}= \frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{1-p}{2}+\frac{p}{2}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{2}(1-|2p-1|) = \frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{4} |2p-1|
\end{align}

**Question:**
I know this is wrong, because that must be 1 when $p=\frac{1}{2}$ (recurrent random walk). However that is not the case with my solution. Can you guys tell me where I went wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure where you went wrong or even what is the decomposition you are using, but anyway, assuming $p\geqslant\frac12$, the probability $h_{-1}$ to hit $0$ starting from $-1$ is $h_{-1}=1$ and, using Markov property after one step of the walk, one sees that the probability $h_1$ to hit $0$ starting from $1$ solves $h_1=1-p+ph_1^2$, thus $h_1=(1-p)/p$. Thus, the probability $h_0=(1-p)h_{-1}+ph_1$ to come back to $0$ starting from $0$ is $h_0=2(1-p)$, that is, for some general $p$ in $[0,1]$, $$h_0=2\min\{1-p,p\}$$

Comment: @Did Yes, that is kind of the same idea as mine. However I failed to do it correctly. The $h_1$ en $h_{-1}$ correspond a little bit with $\mathbb{P}(\text{Ever returning to 1 without going less than 1} | X_1=1)$ and the counterpart of it respectively. Clearly something went wrong when I tried to calculate it.  I appreciate your help, thanks!